# Compute intersections of all combinations of vectors in a list of vectors in R

Tags: r

My goal is to compute the intersections of several vectors (sets of identifiers, gene-names to be specific). I start with a list of vectors and run the function below, which loops through 1:n where n is the number of sets and then uses [combn](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/combn.html) to generate all combinations of my sets taken m at a time.

I paste together a name and then reduce by intersection over my sets yielding a named list of character vectors holding the elements in common between each combination of sets.

My question is, of course, is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
## Compute the intersection of all combinations of the
## elements in the list of vectors l. Might be useful
## for generating Venn/Euler diagrams.
## There might be better ways to do this!
overlap <- function(l) {
  results <- list()

  # combinations of m elements of list l
  for (m in seq(along=l)) {

    # generate and iterate through combinations of length m
    for (indices in combn(seq(length(l)), m, simplify=FALSE)) {

      # make name by concatenating the names of the elements
      # of l that we're intersecting
      name <- do.call(paste, c(as.list(names(l)[indices]), sep="_"))

      # adding the init=l[indices[1]] parameter helps with the case
      # where we're only dealing with one set, i==1 and length(indices)==1,
      # and we want only unique items in that set.
      # Reduce(intersect, list(c(1,2,3,3))) => c(1,2,3,3)
      # Reduce(intersect, list(c(1,2,3,3)), init=l[[indices[1]]]) => c(1,2,3)
      results[[name]] <- Reduce(intersect, l[indices], init=l[[indices[1]]])
    }
  }
  results
}

overlap( list(foo=c('a','b','c','d','e','e'),
              bar=c('a','c','e','f','g'),
              bat=c('a','b','c','d','g')))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach seems reasonable, but there are some simplifications you can make.

First, your construction of `name` is needlessly complex.  This works just as well:

```
name <- paste(names(l)[indices], collapse="_")
```

Second, you can call `unique` on each element of `l` at the outset which eliminates the need to specify an `init` value to `Reduce` (and thus reducing all the calculations by one call to `intersect`). It also shortens the arguments to `intersect` since duplicates have already been eliminated.

```
l <- lapply(l, unique)
```

These two give a function

```
overlap <- function(l) {
  results <- list()
  # Remove duplicates within each entry of l
  l <- lapply(l, unique)

  # combinations of m elements of list l
  for (m in seq(along=l)) {

    # generate and iterate through combinations of length m
    for (indices in combn(seq(length(l)), m, simplify=FALSE)) {

      # make name by concatenating the names of the elements
      # of l that we're intersecting
      name <- paste(names(l)[indices], collapse="_")

      results[[name]] <- Reduce(intersect, l[indices])
    }
  }
  results
}
```

Further elimination of duplicate work would involve recognizing that higher order interactions, as you are determining them now, are repeating the intersections of the lower orders (that is `foo_bar_bat` first intersects `foo` and `bar` and then intersects that with `bat`, but the intersection of `foo` and `bar` was already determined). And "first" order interactions are just the arguments passed through `unique` (as they were simplified in the previous iteration).

```
overlap <- function(l) {
  results <- lapply(l, unique)

  # combinations of m elements of list l
  for (m in seq(along=l)[-1]) {

    # generate and iterate through combinations of length m
    for (indices in combn(seq(length(l)), m, simplify=FALSE)) {

      # make name by concatenating the names of the elements
      # of l that we're intersecting
      name_1 <- paste(names(l)[indices[-m]], collapse="_")
      name_2 <- names(l)[indices[m]]
      name <- paste(name_1, name_2, sep="_")

      results[[name]] <- intersect(results[[name_1]], results[[name_2]])

    }
  }
  results
}
```

If you really want to eliminate more duplicate calculations, you can assign `names(l)` outside both loops and `length(l)` outside the outer loop.

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks! That's very slick and quite a bit more efficient than what I started with.